# Responsive dropdown navbar with angular-ui bootstrap (done in the correct angular kind of way)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created a JSFiddle with a dropdown navbar using angular-ui-boostrap's module "ui.bootstrap.dropdownToggle": **http://jsfiddle.net/mhu23/2pmz5/**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"> <a class="brand" href="#">
                My Responsive NavBar
            </a>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#/list">Entry 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#/list">Entry 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

As far as I understand this is the proper, angular kind of way to implement such a dropdown menu. The "wrong" way, in terms of angularjs, would be to include bootstrap.js and to use "data-toggle="dropdown"... Am I right here?

Now I'd like to add responsive behaviour to my navbar as done in the following Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ghtC9/6/

BUT, there's something I don't like about the above solution. The guy included bootstrap.js!

So what would be the correct angular kind of way to add responsive behaviour to my existing navbar?

I obviously need to use bootstraps responsive navbar classes such as "nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse". But I don't know how...

I'd really appreciate your help!

Thank you in advance!
Michael

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do it using the "collapse" directive: http://jsfiddle.net/iscrow/Es4L3/
(check the two "Note" in the HTML).

```
        <!-- Note: set the initial collapsed state and change it when clicking -->
        <a ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed" class="btn btn-navbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
           <!-- Note: use "collapse" here. The original "data-" settings are not needed anymore. -->
           <div collapse="navCollapsed" class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
```

That is, you need to store the collapsed state in a variable, and changing the collapsed also by (simply) changing the value of that variable.

---

**Release 0.14 added a `uib-` prefix to components:**

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes

Change: `collapse` to `uib-collapse`.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question directly - he is talking about a dropdown button in the navbar and you are talking about collapsing the whole navbar.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks man, I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why a simple collapsible menu was not working

Comment: Personally, I don't think uib-collapse is the wrong way to go for a nav bar.  I would rather use uib-dropdown.

Answer (score 123):

### Update 2015-06

Based on [antoinepairet's comment/example](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/394#issuecomment-69488620):

Using `uib-collapse` attribute provides animations: http://plnkr.co/edit/omyoOxYnCdWJP8ANmTc6?p=preview

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <!-- note the ng-init and ng-click here: -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="navCollapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

### Ancient..

I see that the question is framed around BS2, but I thought I'd pitch in with a solution for Bootstrap 3 using ng-class solution based on suggestions in [ui.bootstrap issue 394](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/394#issuecomment-17480951):

The only variation from the [official bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) is the addition of `ng-` attributes noted by comments, below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">

    <!-- note the ng-init and ng-click here: -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- note the ng-class here -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="{'in':!navCollapsed}">
  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    ...
```

Here is an updated working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OlCCnbGlYWeO7Nxwfj5G?p=preview (hat tip Lars)

This seems to works for me in simple use cases, but you'll note in the example that the second dropdown is cut off.

Comment: Instead of ng-class you should use 'collapse="navCollapsed"'. because your version doesn't make any animation

Comment: Another improvement: add ng-click="navCollapsed=true" to the last div of your snippet so that the drop down menu collapses after an item as been selected.

Comment: @LarsBehnke but then you also get an animation when the navbar is NOT collapsed and that looks weird.

Comment: The overflow can be made visible by adding overflow: visible to the .panel-group panel tag in the bootstrap.css document

Comment: I can't even get the collapse="navCollapse" method to work at the moment for some reason

Comment: @streetlogics It should be "navCollapsed", you missed a "d" there

Comment: Many of us are on BS2 for legacy projects we don't want the pain of converting.  So why is switching to a BS3 answer one that gets a lot of votes? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins - guess it's just useful :) The accepted answer is for BS2, and I'm not suggesting changing. When I added the answer, I'd arrived looking for a BS3 solution, and didn't find one. I wouldn't mind guessing that the ratio of upvotes between the answers is an informal poll of the technology stack folk are using!

Comment: So this is a great example but I feel it is lacking in keyboard support for it.

Comment: Can anyone get this to animate/transition like the normal dropdown?

Comment: I didn't edit in time, but I changed `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="{'in':!navCollapsed}">` to `<div collapse="navCollapsed">` and the transition worked!

Comment: I must be missing something here, but doesn't this solution result in the desktop version of the menu being collapsed and unviewable, given navbar-toggle is hidden? Even with the updates from the comments this is still the case.

Comment: updated the example.. @NathanHoad, media queries expose the navigation on desktop: `@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
  height: auto!important; ...}`

Comment: Quite important for mental sanity which I lost for the sake of all ;) since angular-ui 0.13 you need ngAnimate if you want transitions. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3676

Comment: If you are using dropdown menu in navbar, the ng-class is also important for setting a class called "open" in the dropdown menu like in the bootstrap example.
<li class="dropdown" ng-class="{open: !isDropDownCollapsed}">

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if anyone is having the same responsive issue, but it was just a simple css solution for me.

same example

```
...  ng-init="isCollapsed = true" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"> ...
...  div collapse="isCollapsed"> ...
```

with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .collapse{
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should prepend the .collapse selector with the nav's id so it doesn't screw every collapse in the page

Answer (score 1):

My solotion for responsive/dropdown navbar with angular-ui bootstrap (when  update to angular 1.5 and, ui-bootrap 1.2.1)
`index.html`

```
     ...    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-toggle-cbox">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <label for="navbar-toggle-cbox" class="navbar-toggle" 
                       ng-init="navCollapsed = true" 
                       ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed"  
                       aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </label>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                 <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse"  ng-class="{'in':!navCollapsed}">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/view1">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/view2">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li uib-dropdown>
                            <a href="#" uib-dropdown-toggle>Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button">
                                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>                                   
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

`app.css`

```
/* show the collapse when navbar toggle is checked */
#navbar-toggle-cbox:checked ~ .collapse {
    display: block;
}

/* the checkbox used only internally; don't display it */
#navbar-toggle-cbox {
  display:none
}
```