# Bootstrap data-toggle reloads page when paired with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is similar with [issue 19930383](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930383/)

```
<div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only" style="background-color:white">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="header-logo" ng-click="go('/start', 'slideUp')">
            <img src="image.png" alt="" class="">
            <div id="bluebar"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

The issue is that I can only expand the collapsed navbar, can't shrink it back.

I realized that whenever I click the navbar-toggle button, the page reloads itself.

I already tried to remove the 'data-toggle' attribute, which makes the page stop reloading (and the bar stops expanding), so that must be what's causing this behavior.

**edit** Thanks for the help, **I solved it with angular-ui**, as recomended by charlieftl and l34p3r

Comment: get rid of bootstrap.js http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more detail to chartlietfl's comment above, Bootstrap.js and Angular are somewhat at odds with one another in this case. Angular invites the use of [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to handle interface components with JavaScript. If you wanted to use Bootstrap with Angular, you'd have the easiest time using [Angular-ui Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), which gives you all of the Bootstrap.js functionality wrapped in Angular directives. Using ui-bootstrap will definitely cut down on the code you need to use to apply Bootstrap's JS functionality separately.

[Here's another question that benefitted from converting to ui-bootstrap from the standard Bootstrap functionality when using a button trigger for toggling a collapsible element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21556009/1096711). The difference between the HTML in the questions and the answer can be used as a model for comparing how your code could look before and after ui-bootstrap integration. Specifically, look at how they swapped out `data-toggle` in favor of using `ngClick` to toggle collapsed state.

Hope that helps.