# Angular UI Bootstrap responsive Navbar dropdown not working properly in new version

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, nav

I just created an `AngularJS` project with `grunt` `bower` and `Yeoman`. Included Updated version to `Angular 1.3.13`. I want to use `Angular UI` bootstrap. I added Nav Bar which is responsive. But while on small screens, the drop down doesn't seem to work. When I click on dropdown the entire menu hides.

here is my **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body ng-app="webClientApp">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    ng-init="navCollapsed = true"
                    ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Web Client</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'" ng-click="navCollapsed=true">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul></li>

                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
    <script>
        !function(A, n, g, u, l, a, r) {
            A.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l, A[l] = A[l] || function() {
                (A[l].q = A[l].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, A[l].l = +new Date, a = n.createElement(g), r = n
                    .getElementsByTagName(g)[0], a.src = u, r.parentNode
                    .insertBefore(a, r)
        }(window, document, 'script',
                '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using all latest versions of JS. Here is my **bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "web-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.2",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.13",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.13",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.13",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.13",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.13",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.13",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.13"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "webClientApp"
}
```

The nav bar on full screen is working fine. But when I resize the browser size, The responsive bar is working. **Menu will show up only on clicking the toggle buton. But when I click on drop down menu, the entire menu hides.**

I have followed this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16268606/2353403) and I got one [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OlCCnbGlYWeO7Nxwfj5G?p=preview) for it. It is working fine there.

But I'm using Latest versions of all files. So mine is not working. Here is [my code what I tried in Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SMJaBBJhwoXsE8bZNQ9R?p=preview).

How to Solve this Issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your dropdown portion has changed.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dUGbvnmc089C9rnKFh4f?p=preview)

```
<li dropdown>
     <a href="#" dropdown-toggle>Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
          ....
     </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: So it becomes attribute instead of class?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED for AngularJS 1.5+ and angular-ui-ootstrap 2.5+**

I tried several options for a working dropdown menu in AngularJS 1.5+ and UIBootstrap in the menu bar - nothing worked and was outdated, so I thought I'd share my solution here, also available in [this repo commit](https://github.com/aredfox/todo-angularjs-typescript/commit/a2967dfb966c5e0902adc5adc05bf23166dce7ec#diff-a139ff8e90470b99125cafc67812d753).

#### What I did

1. Used the normal navbar example from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#collapse
2. Combined it with button dropdown functionality as showcased in there from the example on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#dropdown

#### The code (please ref to points 1 & 2 above for further guidance)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ToDoSth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li uib-dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
                <a href id="simple-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>Link 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem 3</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubItem 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li uib-dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
                <a href id="simple-dropdown" class="nav-text" uib-dropdown-toggle>Signed in as John Doe <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Against the latest version of ui.bootstrap, 0.12.1, I think it should be a combination solution on Dropdown and Collapse of ui.bootstrap:

1. for Dropdown menu item, it use "dropdown" in outer element, and "dropdown-toggle" in inner element to trigger the dropdown action;

   ```
   <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
       Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   ```
2. for the navbar collapse button, in responsive mode, it need to add "Collapse" directive in navbar toggle button and navbar div.

   ```
   <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
       <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
       <hr>
       <div collapse="isCollapsed">
           <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div> 
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

for implementation, please refer to: [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dEjtDx8gjoCTkZndNFa9?p=preview)