# Responsive menu (Mobile device) with angular js + bootstrap not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Currently working on **angular js** and bootstrap here I am not using any jquery plugin for the responsive mobile design when i click the icon from the right side of my page. The menu was not showing expanding.

Here is the code i am using for **Toggle navigation** `ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed"`

I searched in SO and got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268606/responsive-dropdown-navbar-with-angular-ui-bootstrap-done-in-the-correct-angula) I tried the same but still not working

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rD7e50Mxigf79PH01Cqo?p=info) link Kindly please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Plunker there are some problems in the code:

- you defined the module as 'reak_app' while in the HTML ng-app refers to (a non existing) module named 'plunker'.
- you defined a controller 'MainCtrl' but in the HTML ther is `<body ng-controller="menu">`.

Here is an updated (and working) [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FBqFj6CCEDEzBnPDPSLs?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @beaver could you please explain  me what is ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed" i just copy paste this line but i am not getting this

Comment: The scope property `navCollapsed` is used as boolean toggle for the `collapse` directive of **Angular-ui-bootstrap** (see https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse)